# Root Samsung Galaxy S Duos

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have Samsung Galaxy S Duos (GT-S7562) because I want to use ROEHSOFT RAM Expander (SWAP) application to expand my RAM by using SD Card.

Before using this application, I need to be sure if my device support swap or not, and I need to root my phone to check this.

How to root Samsung Galaxy S Duos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps below:
**I AM NOT RESPONSIBLE IF YOU DAMAGE YOUR PHONE AND THIS WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY**

This will root your phone and install a custom recovery.

**Windows is required**

1. Install the Samsung drivers. (links at bottom of the post)
2. Download the s7562 Rooting Kit.
3. Extract The kit, and open Odin.
4. In Odin click on PDA and choose the Recovery.tar
5. Now, on your device:
    a. Switch on USB debugging
    b.Put Cwm_SuperSU or Cwm_SuperUser, just choose one, I prefer Cwm_SuperSU
    c.Turn your device off and boot it in download mode ( Hold Vol_Down & Home & Power until you see light coming out from the device, then if you see warning click Vol_Up.
6. Connect your phone to the windows pc and you should see this in Odin: `Com:****`
7. Make sure to Have : Auto Reboot & F. Reset time & Pda Checkedd after you done Step 5 & 6.
8. Remove the back Cover of your phone ( you must do that )
9. Now Click on START in odin
10. You should see a Blue bar in the download mode on your device
11. Wait till it's finished.
12. When it finishes. When you see the samsung logo, remove your battery
13. Remove the Usb cable from your device, and reinsert the battery
14. Now you changed your `Stock Recovery`, With CWM_Recovery. Now you want to go to your new recovery, by pressing Vol_Down & Vol_Up & Home & Power release the buttons when you see the samsung logo.

    Note : Your touchscreen is disabled here , move with your Vol_Up / Vol_down and choose with Home button and go back with back button.
15. **Optional** Make a backup in CWM recovery to external Sd-Card.
16. now choose `Install Zip from sdCard` and go to `Choose zip from Sdcard` Or From internal sd Card ( Depends on where you put your Cwm_SUperuser)
17. Now go to where you have put your CWM_Superuser / Cwm_SuperSU and click on the home button, and click yes and now wait till it has finished.
18. Now go back and choose `Reboot System now`.

Now you should have root:-)

Files:
Samsung kies : http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/
Droidzer Rooting kit : http://d-h.st/BtL

Hope my answer helped.

Comment: I am getting below errors in recovery mode..
E:failed to verify whole-file signature
E: signature verification failed

Comment: @shubha what step?

Comment: step 17. i am pressing power button to choose Cwm_SuperSU from external storage of my phone.

Comment: Somewhere in the recovery there should be an option to disable signature verification, and did you successfully install CWM recovery?

Comment: are you talking about installing "Galaxy S Duos S7562 Droidiser Rooting Kit\recovery.tar" from odin? Yes i got a green PASS in that step. Then i downloaded "CWM-SuperSU-v0.94" from the link you have given, and copied it to my external SD card.  the started recovery option and inside that i selected "CWM-SuperSU-v0.94" from SD card, and getting the above errors.. Installation is aborted

Comment: OK try Method 2 of this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2344909

Comment: Hey, Just tried all steps again, This time successfully completed all steps :-) thanks a lot, Now how i will know if my phone is rooted or not?

Comment: Just installed Rootcheck software and checked, Its showing my phone is rooted..

Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

In order to root your Android device, you can download and install **[Root Masters](http://products.mgyun.com/api/downjump?productcode=irootm)** on it, then run the app. At the "ROOT" tab you will see the face of the *Android Jelly Bean* mascot, and at the right side of it there will be a rectangular `root` button. Tap/Touch it. The mascot's face will turn into a "ninja" Jelly Bean face while the app attempts to root your device. If the rooting process is successful, the mascot will smile.

If the rooting process fails, you can download, install and run **[iRoot](http://www.iroot.com)**, which is another neat one-click rooting app for Android. It looks very similar to Root Masters, thus if you managed to use Root Masters then running iRoot will be pretty much straightforward/self-explanatory.

By using any of the above methods, I was able to root the following Android devices:

- Samsung Galaxy S Duos 2 (**GT-S7582L**)
- Samsung Galaxy S Duos (**GT-S7562**)
- Samsung Galaxy Y (**GT-S5360B**), AKA "Galaxy Young"
- Samsung Galaxy W (**GT-I8150**), AKA "Galaxy Wonder"

PS: if by accessing any of the indicated links/URLs your browser gives you an alert of "dangerous" or "malware" website, just **ignore** it and access the website anyway: these are **safe** websites hosting **safe** apps. These alerts happen because these websites host **rooting apps**, and rooting apps are **rootkits** (they execute one or more **exploits**, which are pieces of software that explore the operating system's vulnerabilities in order to get privilege escalation: in this context, root/superuser privilege). There are **no viruses** in these apps: only rootkits. Anyway, if you feel insecure about it, just install an antivirus and let it running on your device while you install and run the rooting app.

PPS: for those with a **Motorola** device, you may want to try **[Kingo Root](https://www.kingoapp.com)**. With the Kingo Root app, I managed to root:

- Motorola Razr HD (**XT925**)
- Motorola Razr I (**XT890**)
- Motorola Moto X (**XT1096**)

Comment: Firefox shows "Reported Attacks Page!" for the first link.

Comment: @Firelord: it's a **false** alert, no need to worry. These rooting apps are *rootkits*, and rootkits are basically groups of **exploits** (pieces of software that take advantage of the operating system's vulnerabilities in order to obtain privilege escalation: in this context, root/superuser privilege). Hence, websites hosting rootkits are frequently flagged as dangerous, as a source of malware et cetera. But all these rooting apps do is to give you root access. Anyway, if you feel insecure just install an antivirus in your device and let it running while you install and run the rooting app.

Answer (score 1):

[KingRoot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/one-click-root-tool-android-2-x-5-0-t3107461) is a possible option - it is a one-click root app which is reasonably easy to use and works for Android versions up to 5.1 on most devices - it has been known to work with the OP's device too.

Do note that KingRoot installs some bloat apps on the device - but those can easily be removed (uninstalled) as they are not system apps.

Comment: @beeshyams , this is an answer, albeit a very, very, extremely poor one. I'll try and edit it to make it more aligned to answer guidelines.

Comment: Warning: King root is impossible to get off the phone.

Comment: For an charcoal reviewers coming here, this is not spam, Kingroot is one of the well known options for rooting an android phone. Although, I'd never recommend it.