# Yellow exclamation mark on boot on rooted Samsung Galaxy device

Tags: root-access, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I have Samsung Galaxy S Duos, and after I rooted it by following [Root Samsung Galaxy S Duos](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/110361/root-samsung-galaxy-s-duos), I had an exclamation symbol when I turn my mobile on.

[image: exclamation symbol on boot]

What happened? What are the consequences now? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> Just tell me what happened....

This is not an error, its just a counter.
It counts, how often the phone downloads custom binary, for example a root-patch or a custom rom.

> what are the consequences now????????????

Just nothing,
This symbole only shows to the manufacturer, or any repair service, that your warranty is lost(cause you rooted your phone)
Its just that - a warning symbole, no errors on device, no performance leaks etc.

> How can i solve it????

There are several patches on the internet, you can patch the counter and force the warning symbole to disappeare.
I have something similar on my LG G4, which says that my bootloader is open, but i dont worry.

Greetings,
Fischmaster

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide sufficient information; such as, if the "yellow exclamation mark" shows, but the phones boots up properly, OR, the phone is stuck on the screen showed in the image you posted.

Generally, that symbol is used to mark unofficial changes to the phone, as Samsung phones maintain a binary counter related to such unofficial modifications.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2078643